# wince-7 -- DHCPV6.DLL : error K.IPHLPAPI.DL

Tags: windows-ce

I have installed the latest version of the wince-7 compact evaluation version & getting following error.

Please suggest why basic project created & compilation is giving following error.

```
d:\workingfolder\gatewayupgrade\testce7image\testce7image\wince700\bsptemplate_x86_retail\cesysgen\oak\target\x86\retail\DHCPV6.DLL : error : Missing module 'd:\workingfolder\gatewayupgrade\testce7image\testce7image\wince700\bsptemplate_x86_retail\cesysgen\oak\target\x86\retail\K.IPHLPAPI.DLL' referenced
d:\workingfolder\gatewayupgrade\testce7image\testce7image\wince700\bsptemplate_x86_retail\cesysgen\oak\target\x86\retail\DHCPV6.DLL : error : Unresolved import due to missing export 'GetAdaptersAddresses' from module 'd:\workingfolder\gatewayupgrade\testce7image\testce7image\wince700\bsptemplate_x86_retail\cesysgen\oak\target\x86\retail\K.IPHLPAPI.DLL'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'if' : return code '0x200'
Stop.
SYSGEN: ERROR: error(s) in sysgen phase ( common )
CEBUILD: BUILDMSG: Building application trees: 
SysgenPlatform: BUILDMSG: Sysgening platform C:\WINCE700\platform\BSPTemplate

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.199
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Cefilter platform files
    if not exist "D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files" mkdir "D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files"
    if exist "D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files\config.bib" del "D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files\config.bib"
    cefilter -D C:\WINCE700\platform\BSPTemplate\files\config.bib D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files\config.bib
Cefilter for Windows CE (Release) (Built on Jul 25 2008 12:58:40)
    copy D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files\config.bib + D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\oak\files\commonfixupvar.bib D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files\config.bib
D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files\config.bib
D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\oak\files\commonfixupvar.bib
        1 file(s) copied.
    cefilter -D C:\WINCE700\platform\BSPTemplate\files\platform.bib D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files
Cefilter for Windows CE (Release) (Built on Jul 25 2008 12:58:40)
    cefilter -D C:\WINCE700\platform\BSPTemplate\files\platform.dat D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files
Cefilter for Windows CE (Release) (Built on Jul 25 2008 12:58:40)
    cefilter -D C:\WINCE700\platform\BSPTemplate\files\platform.db  D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files
Cefilter for Windows CE (Release) (Built on Jul 25 2008 12:58:40)
    cefilter -D C:\WINCE700\platform\BSPTemplate\files\platform.reg D:\WorkingFolder\GatewayUpgrade\TestCE7Image\TestCE7Image\Wince700\BSPTemplate_x86_Retail\cesysgen\platform\BSPTemplate\files
Cefilter for Windows CE (Release) (Built on Jul 25 2008 12:58:40)
CEBUILD: BUILDMSG: There were errors building. Check C:\WINCE700\build.err

BLDDEMO: ERROR: There were errors building CEBASE.

BLDDEMO: BUILDMSG: BldDemo ended at 15:57:52.41 on Mon 05/27/2013 (exit code 1)
BuildLogs: BUILDMSG: Exiting: BldDemo1.bat  -q (result code 1).
BuildLogs: BUILDMSG: C:\WINCE700\build.log
BuildLogs: BUILDMSG: C:\WINCE700\build.out
BuildLogs: BUILDMSG: C:\WINCE700\build.wrn
BuildLogs: BUILDMSG: C:\WINCE700\build.err
```

Even after updating as per this link :--
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2711535

Getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a dependency somewhere that relies on TCP/IP IP Helper API. If you add this into the catalogue, then the problem should go away.

BSP/Core OS/Windows Embedded Compact/Communication Services and Networking/Networking – General/TCP/IP and add IP Helper API.

Rebuild and it should go away.